# Anything like "white-space: none"?

Tags: css, whitespace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

If I have several child elements with `display:inline-block`, I can't have whitespace between the elements because that messes up the total width. I either have to put no whitespace in the source, or "cheat" by putting an empty `<?php [whitespace] ?>` between the elements, or use JavaScript to remove the empty text nodes.

Is there any way to make the whitespace not be rendered in CSS?

Comment: use negative margines for those inline-block elements?

Comment: Spaces aren't the same width in all browsers (font-rendering engines) though.

Comment: Use `font-size: 0` on the parent element, and restore the font-size for the child elements.

Comment: I've asked this question before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/425275

Comment: @j08691 That wouldn't allow me to center the boxes in their container ;)

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: In my case code:  white-space: break-spaces !important; is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, setting the font-size to 0 on a parent element, and then restoring it on the elements themselves, should fix the problem.

Solution from here: [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Chrome has a "minimum font size" setting though. I think that would break this solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the elements as block-level elements by using `display: block;` or `float: left;`. If you must use `inline-block`, then you'll have to adjust your HTML either by removing the spaces in the HTML itself or stripping it out with Javascript.

As @jValdron pointed out, setting font size to 0 for parent elements, and then re-setting the font size on the elements which need it, also works. There are potential issues with this, however (for instance, what if you have text in the parent element which isn't already wrapped in another element?). Regardless, the `font-size` solution does in fact work and it's one I've used myself, before.

Comment: Exactly what the guy said already.

Comment: 3 down votes for a proper answer? Really? There were no comments when I loaded this post up and wrote out this answer. Regardless, this answer isn't wrong. You should use your down votes in a better way. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette

Answer (score 2):

CSS Tricks has a good article on dealing with the `inline-block` whitespace issue:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: "Remove the spaces": What I'm already doing and am seeking an alternative to. "Negative margin": Relies on space being a specific width. It's not. "Skip the closing tag": I'm using `<div>` tags so that won't work. "Set the font size to zero": Doesn't work in browsers that have a minimum font size accessibility setting. "Just float them instead": Doesn't allow for centering. Sorry.